# Optimal method to find the max of sublist items within list

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

I have a multidimensional list in the format:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 2], [0, 1, 1]]
```

How do I obtain the maximum value of the third value of all the sublists. In pseudo code:

```
max(list[0][2], list[1][2], list[2][2])
```

I know this can be done via iterating over the list and extracting the third value into a new list, then simply performing `max(list)`, but I'm wondering if this can be done using a lambda or list comprehension?

Comment: `max(lis, key=lambda m: m[-1])` or `max(lis, key=lambda m: m[-1])[-1]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj The first will return the list with the max value, not the max value itself.

Comment: ya,  The first will return the list item having the max elem present at the last

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `max` with a generator expression:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 2], [0, 1, 1]]
>>> max(l[2] for l in lst)
3
```

Also, don't name your variables `list`, you are shadowing the type.

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` function to get the list of columns then use a simple indexing in order to get the expected column:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 2], [0, 1, 1]]
>>> 
>>> max(zip(*lst)[-1]) # in python 3.x max(list(zip(*lst))[-1])
3
```

One another alternative and more pythonic approach is passing a `key` function to `max` to get the max item based on the key function. In this case you can use `itemgetter(-1)` in order to get the max item based on intended index then since the `max()` function returns the whole item from your list (sub-list) you can get the expected item by indexing:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(lst, key=itemgetter(-1))[-1]
3
```

Or more functional:

```
>>> key_func = itemgetter(-1)
>>> key_func(max(lst, key=key_func))
3
```

Comment: Note that `zip(...)[-1]` will only work in Python 2.x, and then will be a bit slower than the others.

Answer (score 1):

applying `max` on the list will return the maximum list, which isn't what you want. You could indeed use a list comprehension to extract the third element, and then apply `max` on that comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 2], [0, 1, 1]]
>>> max([x[2] for x in lst])
3
```