# How to find min of second element in the list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a list below:

```
a = [ [8, 12], [13, 9], [2, 5], [1, 10], [13, 13] ]
```

How do I find `5` of `a[2][1]`. I want to find the minimum value of second element of the sub-list.

This is my code:

```
min = a[0][1]
for i in range(len(a)):
  temp = a[i][1]
  if temp < min:
    min = temp
```

What is a good way (with fewer lines of code) to implement this code?

Comment: What about `min(sub[1] for sub in data)`?

Comment: Define 'better'. As long as the list is not sorted by the second element, there is no way to be better(faster) than iteration over the hole list. Possible interpretations of 'better': a) in as few lines of code as possible, b) with as few characters as possible, c) 'easiest' to read for other programmers ...

Comment: Duplicate: [Optimal method to find the max of sublist items within list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655727/optimal-method-to-find-the-max-of-sublist-items-within-list) You only have to replace `max` with `min`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use the built-in function `min` with parameter `key`:

```
a = [ [8, 12], [13, 9], [2, 5], [1, 10], [13, 13] ]
min(a, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a generator that obtains the second element for each sublist with:

```
sub[1] for sub in data
```

So we can pass this to the `min(..)` function:

```
min(sub[1] for sub in data)
```

If not all sublists have at least two elements, we can add a filter conditon:

```
min(sub[1] for sub in data if len(sub) > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see it in another way

- filter to get only the seconds elements, here's some ways

  ```
  seconds = [v[1] for v in a]
  seconds = map(itemgetter(1), a)
  ```
- get the min in this

  ```
  min_val = min(seconds)
  ```

Shorted result

```
min_val = min(map(itemgetter(1), a))
```